# Rounding decimals to a user-specified number of places

Tags: ios, swift, rounding, number-formatting

I have a piece of code for my calculator.

And there is a stepper in the settings.

How can I make it so that when the user presses a stepper on 2 then the answer in the calculator would be rounded to 2 numbers after the decimal point?

---

Now there is a rounding up to 9 numbers after the decimal point.

```
displayResultLabel.text = String(format: "%.9f", newValue)
```

[image]

---

***MainViewController.swift***

```
var currentInput: Double {
    get {
        return Double (displayResultLabel.text!)!
    }
    set {
        let value = "\(newValue)"
        let ValueArray = (value.components(separatedBy:"."))
        if ValueArray[1] == "0" {
            displayResultLabel.text = "\(ValueArray[0])"
        } else {
            displayResultLabel.text = String(format: "%.9f", newValue)
              //displayResultLabel.text = "\(newValue)"
        }
        stillTyping = false
    }
}
```

***SettingsViewController.swift***

```
@IBOutlet weak var Stepr1: UIStepper!

@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
    //let am = NSNumber(value: sender.value)
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.value, forKey: Savings)
    //stepperValueChanged(sender: Stepr1)
    MAXLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.setValue(MAXLabel.text, forKey: "data")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Save value
    if let Savings = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: Savings) {
        Stepr1.value = Savings as! Double
        stepperValueChanged(sender: Stepr1)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Multiply it by 100, use floor or round and divide by 100 again

Comment: if you just want the description rounded you can use NumberFormatter and set the desired roundingMode

Comment: @LeoDabus How can I do this? I do not really understand in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *String Interpolation* in the format String:

```
let places = Int(Stepr1.value)
displayResultLabel.text = String(format: "%.\(places)f", newValue)
```

Note: This will always use `.` as the decimal separator even if the user's locale specifies `,`.  Use `NumberFormatter` to take `locale` into account as shown by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27705739/1630618).

Comment: Does this format correctly based on the user's locale?

Comment: @rmaddy, no not unless your locale uses `.` as the separator.  LeoDabus' answer in the linked [duplicate] uses `NumberFormatter` which does take locale into account.