# Swift rounding to nearest nth decimal

Tags: swift

I've found the documentation for [`remainder(dividingBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/2883914-remainder), yet it's not clear to me how I could use this to say, round `lonlat:[Double]` like so:

```
[-73.983689245631894, 40.72751308705945]
```

to the 6th decimal:

```
[-73.983689, 40.727513]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338573/rounding-a-double-value-to-x-number-of-decimal-places-in-swift

Comment: With fixed precision floating point (`Float`, `Double`), you can't. Consider using `Decimal`, or just using a `NumberFormatter` right before displaying it to a user. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Wow major dup, my bad, sorry.

Comment: Long read, but definitely worth it: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @JPSilvashy Also, don't use array's to hold a fix pair of 2 elements! We have tuples in Swift! And `CLLocationCoordinate2D`!

Comment: @Alexander much appreciated, just getting started this past week, stumbling like a moron! :)

Comment: you can use NumberFormatter and set minimum and maximum fraction digits as well as the routing mode https://stackoverflow.com/a/27705739/2303865

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NumberFormatter`

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
formatter.roundingMode = NumberFormatter.RoundingMode.halfUp
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6 // 6th decimal

let roundedValue1 = formatter.string(from: -73.983689245631894)
```

Reader then can generalize code.

Answer (score 0):

You can cut your number with

```
let formatted = String(format: "number: %.6f", number)
```