# Swift 4.2 round function

Tags: swift

I have func in my app which trims numbers, e.x. 9.81->9.8. But after updating swift behavior has changed.

```
let myNum = 9.7
print(round(myNum / 0.1) * 0.1)

Swift 4.1.2 output - 9.7 
Swift 4.2 output - 9.700000000000001
```

Please advise how to resolve this issue. May it is swift's bug?

Comment: if that is _really_ `4.7` that is a huge bug, indeed – it should be `9.7`.

Comment: This is another variation of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: Sorry) This was typo, 9.7

Comment: You cannot round a `Double` if that "rounded" value cannot be represented as a floating-point number. You should either use `DecimalNumber` if you actually need to store decimals or use a `NumberFormatter` or simply a formatted `String` if you just need the "rounding" for displaying the number on a UI

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Comment: what is the issue, actually here? e.g. `9.81` will output `9.8`

Comment: What's your goal; do you want to round and then get a string with only one decimal digit?

Comment: @Paul https://stackoverflow.com/a/27705739/2303865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the correct value itself, and not just a `String` representation, you can try this.

```
let value = 9.71
let roundedValue = round(value * 10) / 10
print(roundedValue)
```

It prints `9.7` on `Swift 4.2`, so I guess that the rounded value is correct and you can use it for additional computations.

Comment: Thanks. That exactly what I expected

Comment: @Paul what you should use is NumberFormatter

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you want:

```
let trimmedString = String(format: "%@.1f", round(myNum / 0.1) * 0.1)
```