# Formatting a double variable - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm facing a problem with formatting a double variable in iOS Swift

The variables that I have are like for instance `0.7, -4.56, 34.6` but they should be in the format `00.70, -04.56, 34.60`

What's the best way to approach that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Precision String Format Specifier in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24051314/643383)

Comment: Is it really a duplicate of the above mentioned, I wonder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this

```
extension Double {
    func formatNumber(minimumIntegerDigits: Int, minimumFractionDigits: Int, maximumFractionDigits: Int=2) -> String {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = minimumIntegerDigits
        numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = minimumFractionDigits
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = maximumFractionDigits

        return numberFormatter.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}

999.989.formatNumber(minimumIntegerDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2) // => 999.99
9.989.formatNumber(minimumIntegerDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2) // => 09.99
```

Comment: maximumFractionDigits  & minimumFractionDigits both?? I think one needs to be IntegerDigits there.

Comment: @Sh_Khan `NumberFormatter ` require `NSNumber` 
`open func string(from number: NSNumber) -> String?`

Comment: `return numberFormatter.string(for: self) ?? ""`

Comment: @iOSer - yes, you are right, answer updated

Comment: Note that this approach will create a new number formatter each time this method is called. You should declare your number formatter as a static property on Formatter

Comment: @LeoDabus - I won't agree with you on declaring static property all times, by using this approach you will end up declearing everything as static.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339936/swift-double-to-string/27705739?s=1|80.8182#27705739

Comment: No need to create a NSNumber object from your Double. Did you read my other comment above?

Comment: Awesomeness! Saved my day ;)

Comment: This answer does not produce the output it claims. The results are `999.989` and `09.989`. You would also need to set `maximumFractionDigits`.

Comment: @rmaddy updated, thanks :)

Comment: That update will cause problems if the user passes a value of `3` or more to the `minimumFractionDigits` parameter.

Comment: @rmaddy we are here to guide and share ideas on how things can be used. The person using it can tweak according to his/her need.

Comment: And the most up voted and accepted answer should not be edited afterward with bugs. The answer should remain worthy of being up voted and accepted by continuing to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) like so:

```
let number = 0.7

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

numberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2

numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

numberFormatter.string(for: number)
```

Or have it defined as a function:

```
func format(_ x: Double) -> String? {
    guard abs(x) < 100 else {
        print("The argument must have 2 integer digits at maximum")
        return nil
    }

    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

    numberFormatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 2
    numberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2

    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

    return numberFormatter.string(for: x)
}

format(-0.7)  //"-00.70"
format(120)   //nil , and prints "The argument must have 2 integer digits at maximum"
```

Remember that the method [`Formatter.string(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/formatter/1415993-string) returns an optional string.

As pointed out by [**@LeoDabus**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus), to avoid creating a new Number Formatter each time this function is called, we can define a static property on NumberFormatter:

```
extension NumberFormatter {
    static let formatter_2Int_2Frac: NumberFormatter = {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 2
        numberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2

        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        return numberFormatter
    }()
}
```

And thus, the function above will look like this:

```
func format(_ x: Double) -> String? {
    guard abs(x) < 100 else {
        print("The argument must have 2 integer digits at maximum")
        return nil
    }
    return NumberFormatter.formatter_2Int_2Frac.string(for: x)
}
```

Comment: May be `%02.2f`?

Comment: @Cy-4AH though %02.2f would work! This is more correct way of achieving the same.

Comment: you should use Formatter's method `string(for: Any)` and pass a Double

Comment: @LeoDabus cool I've updated the answer

Comment: @LeoDabus I've adopted your suggestion of having an extension on NumberFormatter

Comment: @Carpsen90 make it a property on `Formatter` and name it `number`.  When calling it `Formatter.number.whatever` Note that it is a class so even declaring it as constant, its properties still can be changed. If you need a DateFormatter declare it there also, name it date and so on. You can group all your project formatters there.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
let f = NumberFormatter()

f.minimumFractionDigits = 2

f.minimumIntegerDigits = 2

let str = f.string(from:-4.6)

print(str) // -04.60
```

Comment: you should use Formatter's method `string(for: Any)`

Answer (score 0):

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

let formattedNumbers = [0.7, -4.56, 34.6].flatMap { number in
    return numberFormatter.string(for: number)
}
print(formattedNumbers) //prints ["00.70", "-04.56", "34.60"]
```

Comment: `return numberFormatter.string(for: double)`

Comment: @LeoDabus you mean in my code? Sorry but I do not have a variable called double

Comment: `string(from:)` only works with NSNumber. in your code the compiler infers the type `[NSNumber]` but when coding in Swift you should use Double which is the FloatingPoint native type

Comment: @LeoDabus Agreed and edited