# Exception with NumberFormatter using .spellout in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter, numberformatter

I am testing some strings such as one, two, three, seven, etc. to see if they are numbers using the code below.  It works okay if the string actually is a number but is crashing when the string is not a number as in the word "savings".

The whole point of the method is to find out if the string can be represented as a number so I don't know how to exclude cases where it is not--if indeed that is the problem.  I think that's the problem but I guess I could also be missing something as I'm weak on optionals. The string I am running this on that is producing the error is word "savings".

Here is my code:

```
public extension NSString {
    public var asNum: NSNumber {
               // let stringValue = String(value: self)
                let stringValue = self
                let formatter = NumberFormatter()
                formatter.isLenient = true
                formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
                let num = formatter.number(from: stringValue as String)!///EXCEPTION
                return num
            }
        }
```

The exception reads:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

In the debugger, I can verify that the stringValue is "savings"

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: if string value is equal to "savings" what would you expect to happen forcing to unwrap the result?

Comment: try `return formatter.number(from: stringValue) ?? 0`

Comment: coalescing prevents the exception: return formatter.number(from: stringValue as String) ?? 0  The only problem is 0 is misleading as it could be interpreted as zero which comes up a lot in this use case. I guess I am stuck with picking some weird unlikely number...

Comment: The standard approach in Swift would be returning optional number. `private var number: NSNumber? {`

Comment: Btw you shouldn't declare the number formatter inside your computed property. This will create a new formatter every time you call this property

Comment: The method is called from an Objective-c file.  I don't think it can handle optionals.  Is that correct?

Comment: I know nothing about mixing obj-c and Swift

Comment: The code is actually in an extension.  Where other then where it is could instantiate the formatter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27705739/2303865

Comment: Yes, Objective-C can handle an optional `NSNumber`. It will be returned as `nil`.

Comment: you should use `let num = formatter.number(from: stringValue as String) ?? 0` instead of that code

Comment: As Leo Dabus mentioned, you shouldn't create the number formatter in the computed property. Number formatters are extremely expensive. Create one elsewhere and reuse it.