# Cast from 'Double' to unrelated type 'String' always fails

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I'm getting the data  from the api response
I decoded the data properly 
then I assigned the values to `tableview` cell

But I'm getting the warning

> Cast from 'Double' to unrelated type 'String' always fails

how can I solve this , So that I can assign the double value to the UILabel and get my result

I tried this following code

```
var rate : Double
cell.priceOfVehicleLabel.text = details.rate as? String
```

Comment: see this for help :[Swift double to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339936/swift-double-to-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
cell.priceOfVehicleLabel.text = "\(details.rate)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String's` **`init(describing:)`**, i.e.

```
cell.priceOfVehicleLabel.text = String(describing: details.rate)
```

Comment: This initialiser is only used for generic types. OP should use NumberFormatter which localizes the string to display it respecting the user's device locale and settings. btw https://stackoverflow.com/a/42043333/2303865

Answer (score 0):

It's simply `cell.priceOfVehicleLabel.text = String(details.rate)`.