# Is it possible to add some sort of meta-variable in a String formating enunciate in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, format

I have a function to convert `Double` values to `String`, and add a variable number (from 0 to 3) of trailing zeroes at the end.

In this function, I can do this:

```
var string: String = ""
switch digits {
case 0:  string = String(format:"%0.0f",  doubleValue)
case 1:  string = String(format:"%0.1f",  doubleValue)
case 2:  string = String(format:"%0.2f",  doubleValue)
default: string = String(format:"%0.3f",  doubleValue)
}
```

I would like to have a formatting option like:

```
let string = String(format:"%0.nf", numberOfDigits,  doubleValue)
```

Where we can specify the number of digits (**n**) after the decimal point with a variable (**numberOfDigits**).  I know that the variables should be the values to include in the String, and not a variable of the formatting enunciate..

Is there a way to do it?

Rgds...   e

Comment: You really should use a `NumberFormatter` when converting decimal values for display to a user. Then they are formatted properly for their locale. And you can specify the number of decimal places among other things.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27705739/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the wildcard `*` in the `format:` string to specify a variable value:

```
let string = String(format: "%.*f", numberOfDigits, doubleValue)
```

---

**Example:**

```
let doubleValue = Double.pi

for numberOfDigits in 0...4 {
    print(String(format: "%.*f", numberOfDigits, doubleValue))
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> 3
> 3.1
> 3.14
> 3.142
> 3.1416
> ```

Comment: You don't need string interpolation. Use `String(format: "%.*f", numberOfDigits, doubleValue)`.

Comment: There it is!  Thanks, @rmaddy.

Comment: There are all kinds of fun stuff in the [IEEE printf specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) such as this use of `*`.